# Using esp8266 instead of xbee

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, xbee

I am using xbee pro s2c to get data from arduino (temp, pressure etc.) and I am sending data another xbee module and read these data from serial port.

Question is that I want to use esp8266 instead of xbee. Is it possible? Can I communicate 2 esp module like xbee?

Comment: you would just need one ESP, which connects to both your wifi and the sensor. You could use 2 with ESP-NOW to get a non-wifi module communication going, but it's simpler to use wifi. You also likely don't even need an arduino; sensors can connect directly to the ESP.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two ESP8266 modules talk together, yes. It's not "simple" like an XBee, since you have a generic WiFi network interface, so there's many many different ways of doing it. Typically one would be running as a WiFi Access Point (SoftAP) and the other would connect to it. Then you'd run some "server" code on one module (typically the SoftAP one) and the other acts as a client and connects to it (or sends data to it).